# How do I ssh my Mac from another server?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ssh-tunneling, macintosh, remote-management

I want to ssh my iMac at home from my MacBook when I'm away, but I can't figure out how to ssh when I'm not on the same local network. I have configured my iMac to accept ssh through the "Remote login" setting.

Comment: Repeating a closed question virtually word for word doesn't make it better. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290412/how-do-i-remotely-connect-to-my-imac-from-another-server

Comment: It isn't the exact same question. The other question got closed because it was too broad. Now I tried to narrow it in so that it only was about ssh and not port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe

- install brew
- brew install openssh --with-brewed-openssl --with-keychain-support